# Series with and without zero behave identically-why?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose I am given an arbitrary infinite series.It may contain zeroes,positive numbers and negative numbers.Suppose I now construct another series by eliminating the 0's from the initial series.For example if I have 1+2+0-3+5+0-7-8+12+0+....
then my new series would be 1+2-3+5-7-8+12+.....(a subseries of the 1st one).
Now it is intuitionally obvious that the 2 series behave identically.
But in real analysis,intuition is not enough.We cannot add 0's here like we do in case of finite sum.How do I prove that a series and the series obtained by removing zero's behave identically,I mean they converge or diverge together.If they converge,then converge to the same number,if one of the diverges to infinity or minus infinity other one also.Even when one of them oscillates,the other one also oscillates identically.
Actually if we have 0 terms only upto finitely many terms,then there is not a problem because changing finitely many terms doesn't alter series convergence.
But the series may contain countably infinite number of 0's,then we cannot eliminate those zero's as we do in finite sum.So how can do I prove that those 0's can be removed from the series without changing the nature of the series.My question seems trivial but in real analysis context it is not trivial.

Comment: Note that the series I have written in question is just for understanding what I meant to say,I want to prove the fact for an arbitrary series.

Comment: A series is a sum of a sequence.  Let the first sequence be $a_0, a_1,a_2,.....$ and the second sequence is $b_0, b_1,b_2...$ and has no zeros.  Let $A_k = \sum_{i=0}^k a_k$ and $B_k = \sum_{i=0}^k b_k$.  Then each $B_m$ will equal sme $A_n$ for some $n\ge m$ as both are finite sums with the same non-zero summands.  So how do series "behave"?  Well, the series converge then the converge to $\lim A_k$ and $\lim B_k$.  But the sequence $B_k$ and $A_k$ have the same terms except that $B_k$ stutters a bunch of times.  As we are "going to infinity" the stuttering doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

By introducing $0$'s, what we do precisely is add a finite (possibly empty) string of $0$'s between every two terms in the sum. (This, of course, includes the possibility that there are infinitely many additional zeros.)

Suppose the original series converges. Then there is an $N$ big enough that it will only be $\epsilon$ away from the limit for $n>N$. When we introduce $0$'s, we should change this $N$ to $N'$ by increasing it by however many $0$'s we introduce below it. The set of partial sums after $N'$ is the same as the set of partial sums after $N$ since each partial sum after $N'$ differs from some old partial sum after $N$ by a finite amount of $0$'s, so they're the same. Convergence (to the same limit) immediately follows from this.($\star$)

The converse works similarly -  we remove a finite amount of zeros from in between any two consecutive non-zero terms. Now you might as well keep $N$ the same since the new partial sums after $N$ are just a subset of the old ones.

This establishes the "if and only if statement".

---

($\star$) The argument in this paragraph can be made more rigorous at the cost of clarity. First, take the original sequence $(a_n)$. We'll define $(a_n')$ by first choosing a sequence $z_n;n\ge1$ which tells us how many $0$'s to add between the $n-1$'th and $n$'th term. Given this, we can calculate $Z_n=\sum_{k=1}^nz_k$ which tells us how many zeros we introduce in front of the $n$'th term. Now $(a_n')$ is defined by saying $a'_{n+Z_n}=a_n$ for each $n$ and setting the rest of the terms to $0$. It's clear that $$
S_n=\sum_{k=1}^na_k=\sum_{k=1}^{n+Z_n}a_k'=S_{n+Z_n}'
$$
This can be proved by induction, for example, by noting that $n+Z_n$ is a strictly increasing sequence and so all the terms between $a_{n+Z_n}$ and $a_{n+1+Z_{n+1}}$ are $0$.
Now suppose we have an $N$ such that the partial sums of the original sequence $S_n$ beyond $N$ differ from the limit by less than $\epsilon$. Take $N'=N+Z_N$. Choose any $n'>N'$ and find the first $m'\geq n'$ such that $m'=m+Z_m$ has a solution $m$ (by the definiton of $(a_n')$ arbitrarily large such $m'$ exist, so there is certainly one $\geq n'$). Since all the terms between $a_{n'}'$ and $a_{m'}'$ are $0$, $S_{n'}'=S_{m'}'=S_m$. Also, as $k+Z_k$ is strictly increasing and $m'>N'$, we must have $m>N$, otherwise we would come into contradiction. This finally shows that indeed $S'_{n'}$ differs from the limit by less than $\epsilon$, as desired.

Comment: What about the case when the sequence oscillates?

Comment: My anwer proves that the two sums always either both converge or diverge and that when they converge, the sums are the same. You're asking about oscillatory sequences but at the same time you're interested in a rigorous derivation. For such a derivation, you'd have to provide a more strict definition of "oscillatory" than "it just goes up and down kinda like the sine wave" or something along those lines, otherwise I don't even know what exactly I'm trying to prove.

Comment: The "nature" of the sequence is not a well-defined term on its own. Perhaps the closest to this is that between two partial sums of the original sequence, the partial sums of the new sequence are just the previous sum of the original sequence, which is of course true.

Comment: Oscillating finite sequence :-->Bounded,not convergent.

Comment: Oscillating infinite sequence--->Unbounded,not properly divergent(i.e.does not diverge to +-infinity).

Comment: Or we can also define Oscillating sequence:-->Divergent but not properly divergent.

Comment: Now all the definitions are given,I think now you can try to prove it.

Comment: After introducing the $0$'s, pick the original partial sums out as a subsequence of the new sequence. This subsequence is just the original sequence, so it is improperly divergent. But if any subsequence of a sequence is improperly divergent, the whole sequence is (this is the contrapositive of "if a sequence is convergent or properly divergent, every subsequence is"). Thus introducing $0$'s preserves improper divergence (oscillations by your definition).